# python script to append to [Gmail]/Drafts works for one email address, but not another

Tags: python, gmail, imap, gmail-imap

I have been testing out a little script for uploading drafts to a gmail address like so:

```
now = imap.Time2Internaldate(time.time())
conn.append('[Gmail]/Drafts', '', now, str(msg))
```

This all works just fine for account1@company.com.

I then go through authenticating with a second account, acc2@company.com, and uploading a draft fails with the following error:

```
30:08.43 < EMCK2 NO [TRYCREATE] Folder doesn't exist. (Failure)
30:08.43 NO response: [TRYCREATE] Folder doesn't exist. (Failure)
```

I can create folders, but not append to folders, not even the ones that I create.

Settings in both accounts are identical and both are on the same domain. I have no idea why or how this is happening, or where to look next to find out?

Comment: Couple things: are they set to the same language?  Is one in Germany? (They use [Googlemail])  Try providing '()' for the Flags column.  Also, I'm not entirely sure how good the basic imaplib is about quoting, so I'd also try using '"[Gmail]/Drafts"'.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Max. I've tried all combinations of your three suggestions and am still getting the same error unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

This is because Google uses localized folder names for these special folders. The correct way is making your application work without hardcoded folder names and not gmail-specific in the first place. One way of achieving that goal is via the [RFC 6154](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6154).